# Packaging a Java game for Linux

Tags: java, lwjgl, linux, distribution

I'm just about finished developing a small Java/Lwjgl-based [game](http://www.indiedb.com/games/patent-blaster). For Windows users, I intend to use [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to package the game into a nice .exe. For Mac users, I'll be using JarBundler to produce a nice .app.

What do I do for Linux users? So far I've been distributing beta versions as a .jar file, a lib folder and a shell script for invoking the jar with the right virtual machine parameters. But this is less than pretty. Is there a cross-distro way of providing a single clear way to start the game?

Comment: Java Webstart works in Linux and PC, I haven't tried on Mac. There are occasional compatibility issues with the default Linux open source IcedTea compared to Oracle Java Webstart though. A lot of java programs come as an executable jar and a .bat and .sh script to start it on windows/linux.

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to give the prospective players a nicer experience than a naked .sh file they have to run.

Comment: @Zarkonen Is a .sh any worse than a .exe on windows?

Comment: Starting from the shell is stanard on GNU/Linux. File extensions don't matter a single bit either.

Answer (score 1):

Making a script and putting it somewhere like /usr/bin is the standard way of doing this. Look into .deb packages if you want to package it nicely.

Comment: oh the horror of `deb` packaging.