# Packaging JARs for Linux

Tags: java, linux

I realise that [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49717/packaging-a-java-game-for-linux) exists but the answer doesn't explain how to create `DEB` packages and whether they're suitable.

I'd like to package my Java 8 game for Linux. Most people don't have Java 8 (and some don't even have Java), so including the JRE in the package would be great.

The package should also have a logo that shows up on most desktop environments.

Lastly, the package should be cross distro (or cover a large number of distros), if possible, because there are simply so many distros.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

- DEB is only for Debian based GNU/Linux distributions. If you want a full cover, use a `.tar.gz` compressed archive.
- You can include Java files but review its [Licensing and Distribution FAQs](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml).
- As you have binary not source, it is better extract it in `/opt/<gamename>` folder for all user.

  Create symlink in `/usr/local/bin/<gameshortname>`

  To have an icon and menu launcher, prepare a `<gamename>.desktop` file, to be installed in `/usr/share/applications/`
- Users without root access can extract any where in his `/home/<username>` and modify a new copy desktop file and save it in `/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/`

`.desktop` file is a standard followed by most Free Desktop Environments (gnome, kde, ..). See [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html)